# Moving images folder from public/img to app/assets/img

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm working on an app that store and accesses the images in the public/img directory.  I'd like to switch that to app/assets/img.  Where in the app is the config for that?

Comment: what specific rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.2.8 is the version

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend your user access directly to app/assets.
File in app/assets are source to be precompiled and will be put in /public/assets (default directory for precompiled assets).

So if you put image in  app/assets/img, when precompiled it will be put in public/assets/img.
You can configure location for precompiling destination folder  using:

`config.assets.prefix`

See [rails edge guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more info about assets pipeline